# componentWillReceiveProps not firing when the state gets updated for the first time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have two unrelated components connected to redux. One is a button and the other is the app's HomeScreen.  The plan is to let HomeScreen know when the button is clicked.  So, I have an action and a reducer to pass the status of the button through. This is working fine except that the HomeScreen is not receiving the updates when I click the button for the first time. I have to click the button twice for the state to pull through.

Add Incident Action:

```js
import { PLUS_INCIDENT } from './types';

export const plusIncident = pressed => (dispatch) => {
  console.log('2: action: ', pressed);
  dispatch({
    type: PLUS_INCIDENT,
    payload: pressed
  });
};
```

Button Component:

```
// The action
import { plusIncident } from '../redux/actions/plusIncident';

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

class AddIncidentButton extends Component {
  handleAddButtonPress = () => {
    const { pressed } = this.state;
    const { plusIncident } = this.props;

    const btnState = !pressed;
    this.setState({ pressed: btnState });
    plusIncident(btnState);
  };
...

}
...
export default connect(
  null,
  { plusIncident }
)(AddIncidentButton);
```

Reducer:

```
import { PLUS_INCIDENT } from '../actions/types';

const initialiState = {
  pressed: false
};

function inc(state = initialiState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PLUS_INCIDENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        pressed: !action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

HomeScreen:
The componentWillReceiveProps method only gets called after clicking the button twice.

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  state = {
    pressed: false
  };

 componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const { pressed } = this.props;
    if (pressed !== nextProps.pressed) {
      this.setState({ pressed: !nextProps.pressed });
    }
  }
...
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  pressed: state.inc.pressed
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your reducer

```
import { PLUS_INCIDENT } from '../actions/types';

const initialiState = {
  pressed: false
};

function inc(state = initialiState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case PLUS_INCIDENT:
      return {
        ...state,
        pressed: !action.payload  // remove this and add action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

remove the not(!) operator.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It worked. I also had to remove the 'pressed' from the Homescreen state and rely on the props instead. i.e. using this.props.pressed directly.

Answer (score 2):

Try add componentDidMount() also to be called for first time. componentWillRecieveProps will be called after receiving update:

```
componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({ pressed: !this.props.pressed});
}
```

Hope it works..

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have not tried this but it does look promising. The 3rd answer worked for me. Turns out I made a mistake in the reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Per [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops), componentWillReceiveProps will not be called during initial mounting:

> React doesn’t call UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps() with initial props during mounting. It only calls this method if some of component’s props may update.

You should avoid using componentWillReceiveProps anyway, as the official documentation states using it often leads to bugs and inconsistencies and it is deprecated in newer versions of React.

---

On the other hand, you're completely missing the benefits of using Redux with your approach, as you're copying Redux state to your internal state inside a HomeScreen component that is already subscribed to the Redux store.

If you need to render something based on the value of **pressed**, do it inside the render method like so, and the component will rerender each time the value of **pressed** is updated after some Redux action is called:

```js
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

    render() {
        const pressed = this.props.pressed;

        <div>
            {pressed ? 'button is pressed' : 'button is not pressed'}
        </div>
    }

}



const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  pressed: state.inc.pressed
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeScreen);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is not the initial state I am worried about. After clicking the button I should receive that first update. Please see the answer below this one.

Comment: Got it, glad you've sorted it out. With that, I still recommend avoiding state duplication.